# Columnar figure over full page in one column layout

Tags: floats, wrapfigure

In a one column document, I want to place a tall/narrow figure over the full height of a page - while the text is in a column besides it.

I tried with `wrapfigure` - but it seems to always anchor the figure to the text. This is in the middle of the document - I can't really place it manually to the Beginning of a page.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mwe}

\usepackage{wrapfig}

\begin{document}

\blindtext

\begin{wrapfigure}{o}{0.4\textwidth}
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=0.35\textwidth,height=0.9\textheight]{example-image-a}
\end{center}
 \caption{Caption}
\end{wrapfigure}

This text seems to be necessary to reset the width of \Blindtext

\end{document}
```

How can I achieve this? A 50/50 split between text and figure would be acceptable if need be.

Answer (score 1):

This may work:

```
full page of text
\twocolumn  % starts a 2 column page
\begin{figure}
 tall enough to fill the column
\end{figure}
text for the adjacent column
\onecolumn % starts a 1 column page
full pages of text
```

This is not automatic, *you* have to decide where in your source you put the `\twocolumn` and `\onecolumn`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this may be an improvement on wrapfig, but I really tried to get around manually setting pages :-(.

Comment: I really recommend `usepackage{multicol}` if you want to make multiple page multicolumn texts. It also works great for breaking the columns to inserts a horizontal figure.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have misunderstood your question. If I am correct now, you have a large document where you need to be able to insert a images that are full page height and 1/2 width. Thus you don't actually want to use any multicolumn formatting as you would have to manually choose the start and stop of the formatting. What you actually want is for the figure to auto place itself on the page and for the text to flow around it.

I think you actually do want to use the wrapfigure. I took a look at its options and you can enable floating by using a capitol letter for placement. Your examples uses a `{o}`

But if you do something like this with a `{L}` or `{R}` or even `{O}` I predict it gets you what you want.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{geometry}           %for page layout
\geometry{hmargin={1in,1in},vmargin={0.75in,0.75in},marginparwidth={0.8in},marginparsep={0in}}

\usepackage{mwe}

\usepackage{wrapfig}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-8]

\lipsum[9-10]

\begin{wrapfigure}{O}{0.5\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.48\linewidth, height=0.95\textheight]{example-image-a}
    \caption{Stretchy Gecko}
    \label{fig:my_label}
\end{wrapfigure}

\lipsum[11-50]

\end{document}
```

------------------------------------------------------------------------Old Answer Below

Try this.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{geometry}           %for page layout
\geometry{hmargin={1in,1in},vmargin={0.75in,0.75in},marginparwidth={0.8in},marginparsep={0in}}

\usepackage{multicol}%allows easy multiple columns
    \columnsep=5ex%column separation

\usepackage{lipsum} %for bogus text generation


\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}

\lipsum[1]%print paragephs
\lipsum[2]
\lipsum[3]

\parindent=0in\rule{\linewidth}{8 in}%replace with your figure

\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```